# Why React is not seeing scss styles

Tags: reactjs, sass

im little bit React noobie when it comes to project setup. I have created a simple project with defaults using `npx create-react-app`. I wanted to use Sass so I installed a sass module. When it comes to usage, I created `styles.scss` with basic background styling, and tried:

```
function App() {
return \<div className="container"\>app\</div\>;
}

export default App;
```

this works fine, but I wanted to use it this way:

```
import styles from "./styles.scss";
function App() {
return <div className={styles.container}>app</div\>;
}
export default App;
```

but it doesn't work. I see that any className is given to this div. I quite don't understand why. Could anybody explain me the difference and give any tips how can I start using the second option mentioned?

Comment: I think you've mistaken css modules and sass

Comment: hmmm, I see that making it styles.module.scss helps to use `import styles from "./styles.module.scss` in className as I wanted :D

Comment: thanks @Konrad, actually it's the solution I was looking for...

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to import a stylesheet, you should simply use:

```
import './styles.scss';
```

Of course you should also have SASS installed in your project, but I assume you already do.